# Using text box value if user selects combobox value?

Tags: excel, vba

I have made a combo box within a userform:

```
private sub Userform_Activate
    cmbLocation.AddItem "Field"
    cmbLocation.AddItem "Remote"
    cmbLocation.AddItem "Other"
end sub
```

when a user selects `Other` I'd like a text box to populate for free form text input. When the user does this, I'd like that text to be the .value that is populating into the worksheet table.

is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a textbox and set it to `.visible = False` when the userform is activated. Then using an if statement you can output the data from either the combobox or the textbox.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Me.txtLocation.Visible = False
    Me.cmbLocation.AddItem "Field"
    Me.cmbLocation.AddItem "Remote"
    Me.cmbLocation.AddItem "Other"
End Sub

Private Sub cmbLocation_Change()
    If Me.cmbLocation.Value = "Other" Then
        Me.txtLocation.Visible = True
    Else
        Me.txtLocation.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If Me.txtLocation.Visible = True Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = Me.txtLocation.Value
    Else
        Thisworkbook.Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = Me.cmbLocation.Value
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Modify sheet and range as necessary

Comment: hm, it was working before (showing the text box based on true/false statement), but it randomly stopped following the logic and never hides the text box. Any clue why?

Comment: Did you change the name of either box?

Comment: must've been something off, got it working again. Appreciate your help!